# Symfony2 Forms: Retrieving data from entity field

Tags: php, symfony

I feel like I am missing something obvious here, I have an entity form field that gives a list of users to select from , the idea here is creating a project and associate it with that (or several) users. I achieved this without much problems but I can't figure out how to access and work with that form field.

Here's how I am setting the form field:

```
->add('user', 'entity', array(
'class' => 'DevUserBundle:User',
'label'  => 'Assigned Users: ',
'multiple'=> true,))
```

In the controller I do the following:

```
$data = $form->getData();
```

I can access the field with `$data['user']` but beyond that I am lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see which user has been selected, the synthax is similar to what you suggested:

```
$usersSelected = $form["user"]->getData();
```

### EDIT

The reason why you have such a long list in your `print_r($userSelected)` statement is because `$userSelected` is an array of `User` objects. Indeed, as you can see in your builder: `->add('user', 'entity'...)`

You can verify this this way

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($usersSelected as $user)
{
    echo "User number ".$i;
    echo get_class($user);
    //Assuming that you have the method getUsername() in you User entity
    echo "Username is".$user->getUsername();
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: doing print_r on this gives a very long winded object which I was having problems with before, how do I navigate this object to get the usernames selected?